# Dialogflow API V2 "End of conversation" flag in webhook request

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am migrating a Dialogflow agent to API V2, and I am having an issue related to the "Set this intent as end of conversation" option

[image]

My fulfillment webhook relies on the `"endConversation": true` property of the V1 webhook request's metadata to perform custom platform logic.

Is there any way I can expose this same property in Dialogflow V2 without using a custom payload?

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the `queryResult.diagnosticInfo.end_conversation` field in Dialogflow's v2 webhook requests the form of which you can see below:

```
{
  "queryResult": {
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "end_conversation": true
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Curiously, this is stored at the agent level. If you export an agent, you'll notice an `endIntentIds` key in the `agent.json` file, which is an array of IDs of the intents that have this flag set.

I'm not sure why this isn't stored on the intent. Since [you have to fully export the agent via the v2 API in order to see agent-level settings](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent), you'll have to do that and then unzip the file in order to determine whether or not this flag is set on an intent.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that this information is accessible via inbound webhook fulfillment requests. Check out [matthewwayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939218/109663).

Answer (score 0):

I am using `streamingDetectIntent` method of `sessionClient`.

In the callback I got `diagnosticInfo` as follows.

```
diagnosticInfo: { fields: { end_conversation: { boolValue: true, kind: 'boolValue' } } }
```

So I am using the following way to determine whether it is last intent.

```js
isLastIntent = data.queryResult && data.queryResult.diagnosticInfo && data.queryResult.diagnosticInfo.fields
           && data.queryResult.diagnosticInfo.fields.end_conversation && data.queryResult.diagnosticInfo.fields.end_conversation.boolValue;
```